# How to compute the ranking (of dates) by groups faster with data.table and lubridate?

Tags: r, date, data.table, lubridate, ranking

I need to compute the ranks of dates by group.
There are many small groups.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(1)
NN <- 1000000
EE <- 10   
# Just an example.
todo <- data.table(id=paste0("ID",rep(1:NN, each=EE)), 
          val=dmy("1/1/1980") + sample(1:14000,NN*EE,replace=T))
# I want to benchmark this:
todo[,ord := frank(val, ties.method="first"), by=id]
```

In order to compare it you can try with smaller NN, the timing is linear.

For NN = 1 million it takes 560 seconds.

Is there any way to do it faster?
I've been using lubridate but I can use any library you suggest.
In my real problem the number of rows within each ID is not constant.

Comment: I have also had the idea of adding large numbers , unique and increasingly large for each ID, ranking alltogether, and then undoing the "transformation". But I would need double precision or some special method to prevent rounding errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it is due to the overhead of calling `frank` multiple times for many small groups (the memory usage below should give you a hint on the bottleneck). Here is another option:

```
DT1[order(id, val), ord := rowid(id)]
```

timing code:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1L)
NN <- 1e6
EE <- 10
todo <- data.table(id=paste0("ID",rep(1:NN, each=EE)),
    val=as.IDate("1980-01-01") + sample(1:14000,NN*EE,replace=T))
DT0 <- copy(todo)
DT1 <- copy(todo)

bench::mark(
    todo[, ord := frank(val, ties.method="first"), by=id],
    DT0[, ord := rank(unclass(val), ties.method = "first"), by = id],
    DT1[order(id, val), ord := rowid(id)])

all.equal(todo$ord, DT0$ord)  
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(todo$ord, DT1$ord)  
# [1] TRUE
```

timings:

```
  expression                                                             min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory time 
  <bch:expr>                                                           <bch> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list> <lis>
1 todo[, `:=`(ord, frank(val, ties.method = "first")), by = id]        6.32m  6.32m   0.00264    15.7GB    0.177     1    67      6.32m <df[,~ <df[,~ <bch~
2 DT0[, `:=`(ord, rank(unclass(val), ties.method = "first")), by = id] 1.12m  1.12m   0.0149     99.3MB    0.969     1    65      1.12m <df[,~ <df[,~ <bch~
3 DT1[order(id, val), `:=`(ord, rowid(id))]                            7.85s  7.85s   0.127     236.8MB    0         1     0      7.85s <df[,~ <df[,~ <bch~
```

---

It can be even faster if we remove `id` in `order`:

```
DT1[order(val), ord := rowid(id)]
```

timing code:

```
bench::mark(DT0[order(id, val), ord := rowid(id)], 
    DT1[order(val), ord := rowid(id)])
all.equal(DT0$ord, DT1$ord)
# [1] TRUE
```

timings:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  expression                                     min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result                    memory            time     gc              
  <bch:expr>                                <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>                    <list>            <list>   <list>          
1 DT0[order(id, val), `:=`(ord, rowid(id))]    7.44s    7.44s     0.134     237MB        0     1     0      7.44s <df[,3] [10,000,000 x 3]> <df[,3] [15 x 3]> <bch:tm> <tibble [1 x 3]>
2 DT1[order(val), `:=`(ord, rowid(id))]        4.66s    4.66s     0.215     237MB        0     1     0      4.66s <df[,3] [10,000,000 x 3]> <df[,3] [14 x 3]> <bch:tm> <tibble [1 x 3]>
```

Comment: @Frank, thanks for the fix. I believe leaving out id inside order will work also. Will test after lunch

Comment: In fact after computing the ranks I was also doing 
    setorder(todo,id,ord)
Maybe I can condense both lines.
I was using that method to avoid problems with ties.

Comment: Now I'm confused. I don't know whether I need to use order or rank

Comment: if u need the rank for subsequent calculations then u should store it in a column. if u just want it to be sorted then use `setorder` or `setkey` (the latter if u are going to use it for subsetting or joining)

Answer (score 3):

I tried a few setups and found the biggest improvement in using `rank(unclass(val), ties.method = "first")` - the base R equivalent of `frank()`. For some reason it outperforms `frank()`when grouping is involved.

```
# Output from microbenchmark::microbenchmark()
Unit: seconds
                                                       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
         todo[, frank(val, ties.method = "first"), by = id] 599.8309 599.8309 599.8309 599.8309 599.8309 599.8309     1
 todo[, rank(unclass(val), ties.method = "first"), by = id] 111.4396 111.4396 111.4396 111.4396 111.4396 111.4396     1
```

Comment: I have also tried frank(unclass(val)) and it's slower too.

Comment: @skan but you do get the same improvement as I do when using base::rank()?

Comment: I mean for now your solution is the fastest. The problem is not unclass, but frank by group, it's not related with the fact of being a date.
frank seems to be 6 times slower (10 in my computer).

Comment: I have just opened an issue https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3988

Comment: @skan, as of 2023, I still get roughly 6x slower